# MySQL DELETE - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is the a way to rewrite this query so i wont get this message `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'` for:

```
DELETE FROM city WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM city_data LIMIT 10000);
```

any ideas?

Comment: Just for curiosity  ... how many distinct states you have in your table ?

Comment: made some edits, so that we stay away from `state`

Comment: Why the limit ?  si mandatory ?

Comment: YES - ints normal and have never been worked

Comment: the limit is there, cuz there are a lot of records

Answer (score 1):

You can change your query to

```
DELETE
FROM city 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM city_data )
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the limit is not a must  you can

```
 delete c.* 
 from city as c
 inner join city_data as cd on cd.id = c.id;
```

Comment: the limit is there, cuz there are a lot of records

Comment: If you haven't in and limit .. you can only use inner join and eventually some where clause related to proper group of values ..